# Shopify After APP Installation in Store / Show Iframe to every Client without Login

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iframe, heroku, shopify

After I installed my APP in Google Chrome, I noticed that if I open the Store in Safari, It show a Install the APP page in my Iframe. I don't want my clients to see that Installation Process. If someone Installed the APP in the Store, I want to check if the Store has Installed the APP and show the Iframe without authentication.

The Iframe query the Price of the Product with Heroku to another API. I use Rails, as shown in the 5 minute APP.

See this image showing the message:

[image: Shopify Store Product Page Installation]

and this one without (desired):

[image: Shopify Store Product Page - API Call to Price]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If an iframe works (your information is scrictly informational) then its src attribute should be to a root relative [proxy url](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies). The application proxy can return liquid that Shopify will interpret for you.

Comment: Nice @bknights !! It works !! And how can I remove the Header and Footer of the Page?

Comment: Add `{% layout none %}` to the top of your generated proxy response

Comment: Perfect!!

But now I have another Problem... When I use

@product = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(id)

In my Proxy Controller, I'm receiving an error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `path' for nil:NilClass):

I don't know how to get a Product and then Save it.

Comment: Sorry that's a whole different question. I use node so would not be much help with Ruby.

Comment: But why when I used the AuthenticatedController it works, and now that I'm using the AppProxyController don't